# Counting variables during recursion

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I want to create a program, which should determine the differences between two lists with equal length and give out the number of differences in a variable. My code so far is:

```
difference([],[],0).
difference(L1,L2,N) :- 
    L1=[H1|T1], 
    L2=[H2|T2], 
    H1=H2, 
    difference(T1,T2,N).
difference(L1,L2,N) :- 
    L1=[H1|T1],
    L2=[H2|T2],
    H1\=H2,
    NZ is N + 1,
    difference(T1,T2,NZ).
```

The program works for two identical lists, but it doesn't count the differences between to lists, for example "difference([1,2,3],[1,2,4],N)" gives me the error "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated". How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either one of: don't use tail-recursion; use an accumulator; use clp(fd) for the counter. Plenty of examples of all three approaches here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't know how to use one, can you implement in my code? Thanks!

Comment: No, you should first look on your own, try to code it, and ask if you have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. The problem is this line `NZ is N + 1` where `N` has not yet been instantiated, `NZ` can not possibly wait for the `N` to be instantiated.

The solution is to get NZ and then add the `1`.

```
difference([],[],0).
difference(L1,L2,N) :- 
    L1=[H1|T1], 
    L2=[H2|T2], 
    H1=H2, 
    difference(T1,T2,N).
difference(L1,L2,N) :- 
    L1=[H1|T1],
    L2=[H2|T2],
    H1\=H2,
    difference(T1,T2,NZ),
    N is NZ + 1.
```